# How to iterate an Objects values and replace undefined with null using lodash?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I know how to do this using native Object.entries and a reducer function. But is it possible to replace that with a lodash function?

```js
const object = {
  foo: 'bar',
  baz: undefined,
}

const nulledObject = Object.entries(object).reduce(
  (acc, [key, value]) => ({
    ...acc,
    [key]: typeof value === 'undefined' ? null : value,
  }),
  {}
);

// {
//   foo: 'bar',
//   baz: null,
// }
```

My desire would be something like:

```js
_cloneWith(object, (value) => (typeof value === 'undefined' ? null : value));
```

Comment: Your code creates a whole new object on each iteration of `.reduce()`, copying all properties accumulated so far. Instead you could just set `acc[key]` as necessary and return `acc`.

Comment: Have you tried `_.reduce()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think [`_.assignWith`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#assignWith) is what you're looking for:

```
const nulledObject = _.assignWith({}, object, 
    (_, value) => typeof value == 'undefined' ? null : value);
```

Answer (score 3):

I found another solution after posting this question:

```js
const nulledObject = _.mapValues(object, 
    (value) => (value === undefined ? null : value));
```